# Not getting Range header

Tags: http, request, google-drive-api, http-range

I am trying to resume an upload from google drive, I have the id of the file when I close the connection I make this session after the Internet is connected again:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUri);
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "bytes */" + FileByteArray.Length);
            try
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
               fileRange = e.Response.Headers.Get("Range");
            }

        }
```

I am not getting the Range header, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-Range` indicates which range of the original entity is contained in the body of either a request (like your `PUT` request) or a 206 partial response. `Range` is set by the *client* not the server in order to request a sub-range. I would assume that the server you are talking to will not respond with the uploaded chunk, so a `Content-Range` (and `Range` in no case) will not be present as a response header.

In your code snippet the actual upload range is missing for `Content-Range` (see the [updated HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2)). It has to have the form of:

```
Content-Range: bytes 42-1233/1234
```

which means: upload byte 42-1233 of an entity whose total size is 1234 byte.

Or when the complete length is unknown:

```
 Content-Range: bytes 42-1233/*
```

So remove the check for the `Range` header and specify the complete upload range and you should be fine.

Comment: Just needed to add on my upload request 
            uploadReq.AddRange(FileByteArray.Length.ToString(), 0, FileByteArray.Length - 1);
And it worked, thanks